# System.OutOfMemoryException when images are displayed in a pivot control

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have an application with a pivot control.i am getting out of memory exception when binding image url source dynamically.Please help me out.Thanx in advance

Sample code:
XAML

```
<phone:Pivot x:Name="PivotProductImages"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,77" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductItems}" SelectionChanged="PivotProductImages_SelectionChanged" >
        <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate >
                <Image Source="{Binding ProductUrl}"></Image>
            </DataTemplate>
        </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot>
```

c#

```
private ObservableCollection<string> objProductimg = new ObservableCollection<string>();


protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
 objProductimg.Add("http://media.testing.com/v2/images_content_split/12594/products_1853164_image1_original.jpg.ashx?quality=90');
 objProductimg.Add("http://media.testing.com/v2/images_content_split/12594/products_1853164_image2_original.jpg.ashx?quality=90');
 PivotProductImages.ItemsSource = ProductItems}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the images you download are too large, Windows Phone platform gives you the oportunity to decode them at a specific size. This way, even if your image is 1800 x 1000 for example, you will keep in memory the same image, but at a lower resolution.

```
    <phone:Pivot x:Name="PivotProductImages" Width="100"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,77" ItemsSource="{Binding ProductItems}" SelectionChanged="PivotProductImages_SelectionChanged" >
    <phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <Image>
               <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="100" UriSource="{Binding ProductUrl}" \>
           </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</phone:Pivot>
```

If you set only one of the DecodePixelWidth or DecodePixelHeight, the image will be decoded at the desired size and  same aspect ratio. By setting both of them to a value, you will decode the all images at the same ratio. This will be problematic if you have many pictures with different sizes.
I hope this will help you.